# Force applications to use TLS 1.2 for certain domains

Tags: debian, openssl

I have a Debian Buster server that is unable to establish an HTTPS/SSL connection to several servers unless I force a TLS 1.2 connection using the `openssl s_client -tls1_2` command.

The errors from various clients are:

- openssl s_client - "SSL handshake has read 0 bytes"
- wget - "GnuTLS: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated."
- curl - "OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL"
- dotnet nuget restore - "Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream."

openssl.cnf already has `MinProtocol = TLSv1.2` by default.

The impacted servers are:

- api.nuget.org
- packages.microsoft.com
- production.cloudflare.docker.com

How do I force my server to use TLS 1.2 when connecting to these domains?

Comment: You don't even mention the error you're facing...

Comment: @Ginnungagap I didn't think the errors were relevant to my question, but I have added them.

Comment: Did you alter openssl.cnf then? What changes did you make?

Comment: @MichaelHampton openssl.cnf was already configured how it should be and the permissions are correct. I tried changing `CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2` to 1 because I had read that fixes some SSL handshake issues for certain clients. But it did nothing. I also tried changing MinProtocol to TLSv1.1 for the same reason. Neither had any impact. I also tried adding `MinProtocol = DTLSv1.2` because that's suggested in the man page. Again, no impact. I have a feeling the file is somehow not being used but I don't have environment variable that overrides it, set.

Comment: The openssl.cnf file was being used. I set `MaxProtocol = TSLv1.2` and it fixed my issue for wget, curl and nuget. apt still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For applications that use OpenSSL, you can set the MinProtocol and MaxProtocol version to TLSv1.2 to force all connections to use TLSv1.2. I know of no way to set this per domain. This is not advisable because some servers only support TLSv1.3, so connections to them will fail.

1. Open openssl.cnf: `vi /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`
2. Scroll to the bottom: Shift-G
3. Insert a new line: Shift-O
4. Add `MaxProtocol = TLSv1.2`

For applications that use GnuTLS, for example apt, you can disable other versions of TLS in the system-wide GnuTLS configuration file, probably /etc/gnutls/config:

```
[overrides]
disabled-version = tls1.0
disabled-version = tls1.1
disabled-version = tls1.3
```

See [Disabling algorithms and protocols](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Disabling-algorithms-and-protocols.html).

Comment: While this answered my question, it didn't solve my problem because it blocked connections to other servers that only support TLS1.3. The ultimate solution was to bypass packet inspection on my firewall for the affected domains. Deep packet inspection on Cisco routers interferes with the TLS negotiation and downgrade from 1.3 to 1.2.